# Problem getting rows between dates in SQL DEVELOPER

Tags: sql, oracle, date, between

I'm trying to get a row result from a table. I created a stored procedure IN SQL DEVELOPER where I can filter between 2 dates

i have the next DATE in my table

```
FECHACARGA - 17/NOV/2020
```

In the sp im trying to compare 2 strings that comes like this:

fechaIni IN VARCHAR2,
fechaFin IN VARCHAR2,

I make this to get the row that matches.

```
SELECT COUNT(1)  
       INTO V_TOTAL
FROM Z_DOMI2_IB_SERVICE_STATUS
WHERE CLIENTE = clientId AND
      TIPOARCHIVO = tipoDeArchivo AND 
      ESTADO = estadoArchivo AND
     TO_CHAR(FECHACARGA, 'DD-MM-YYYY') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(fechaIni, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'DD-MM-YYYY')
                                          AND  TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(fechaFin, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'DD-MM-YYYY');
```

This doesn't work, this gives me nothing just blank.

Thanks!

Comment: please edit the question, show the exact table DLL and the exact table data

Comment: You really should store your dates in proper `date` data type columns

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `TO_CHAR`, just use the `DATE` values:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(1)  
INTO   V_TOTAL
FROM   Z_DOMI2_IB_SERVICE_STATUS
WHERE  CLIENTE = clientId
AND    TIPOARCHIVO = tipoDeArchivo
AND    ESTADO = estadoArchivo
AND    FECHACARGA BETWEEN TO_DATE(fechaIni, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
                      AND TO_DATE(fechaFin, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
```